# K&R C Exercise 1-18 no output/debugging issues

Tags: c, arrays, debugging, codeblocks, kernighan-and-ritchie

I wrote the code below in Code::Blocks as a response to K&R C exercise 1-18:

> Write a program to remove trailing blanks and tabs from each line of
>   input, and to delete entirely blank lines.

I meant it to remove the blanks and tabs (I haven't tackled the blank line part yet).  The `while` loop correctly saves input to the character array `ip`, however, the rest of the code doesn't seem to be working as `EOF` doesn't illicit *any* output at all.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

main(){
    int c, z;
    char ip[MAXLINE];

    z = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        ip[z] = c;
        ++z;
    }

    for (z = 0; ip[z] == ' ' || ip[z] == '\t'; ip[z] = ip[z + 1]);
    printf("%s", ip);

}
```

I was trying to use this issue as a way to learn the debugger, but after I add a breakpoint at line 14, open the watches window, and press the start arrow, nothing happens.  No yellow arrow appears at my break point, my step options are greyed out, and neither my variable names nor their values show up in the watch window.

Advice on fixing my code is appreciated, but what I really want to know is what I'm doing or not doing that is preventing the debugger from helping me.

Comment: Did you provide any input on `stdin`?

Comment: Hint: this is going to be much easier if you only access one line of input at a time instead of the whole file. Your second loop is completely bogus; it will not be triggered at all unless the first character of the input is a space or tab.

Comment: You will need two indexing variables to shuffle the array. One for source, one for dest. Consider what will happen if you have more than one space or tab. An offset of 1 will not work. And: please don't try to put the body of the work of a `for` loop into its conditions - poor style. Lastly don't forget to write a new string terminator `'\0'`

Comment: You are not incrementing `z` in `for (z = 0;...` you lose your character count when you reset `z=0`, and if the file is greater than `1000` chars, you are writing beyond the end of your array in `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)` as you are reading the entire file into `ip`.

Comment: The book has a `getline` function on page 29. I would start with that. Having the whole line in memory allows you to search for the first non-whitespace character starting from the end of the line.

Comment: If you are not forced to use `getchar()` and you can use either `fgets` or `getline()`, then by all means make use of the *line-oriented* input functions. They make it trivial to detect blank lines... Either by the return of `getline` directly or by taking `strlen` of the buffer filled by `fgets` and checking the length (remembering that the `'\n'` is read and included in the buffer filled by either `fgets` or `getline`.

Comment: When running under an OS, there are only a couple (and one optional) valid signatures for `main`  All of them have `int` return type.  Suggest: `int main( void )`

Comment: regarding this line: `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {`  this can easily overrun the input buffer, resulting in undefined behaviour and can easily lead to a seg fault event.  Suggest: `while ( z<MAXLINE && (c = getchar()) != EOF) {`

Comment: regarding this line: `for (z = 0; ip[z] == ' ' || ip[z] == '\t'; ip[z] = ip[z + 1]);`  1) upon executing this line, `z` is indexing the first character in the input buffer. 2) the indexer `z` is never being incremented.  so only the first two characters of the input buffer are being accessed.   Suggest the initializer be `z--`  and decrement `z` in the last parameter of the `for()` statement.  Note: if the first two characters in `ip` are spaces and/or tabs then this `for()` statement will loop forever.  Suggest a careful analysis of what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi. If my answer has solved your problem please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't seeing any output, then this is probably because your program is stuck in the for loop: `for (z = 0; ip[z] ...`, which happens if the string `ip` starts with two consecutive spaces and/or tabs.

The algorithm for removing a certain character is as such:

Have two variables that index a position in the string, destination and source. The code will be inside an outer loop. Source index will iterate in an inner loop until it finds a character that isn't one of the characters that have to be removed or the null character. Then the character from source index is assigned to destination index. The code then checks if source index reached a null character and breaks the outer loop if it did. Both indexes get incremented, the outer loop is then repeated.

In pseudo code:

```
remove = '\t'
string
source = 0 
destin = 0

while
    while string at source equals remove and not-equals null character
        source++
    string at destin = string at source
    if string at source equals null character
        break
    source++
    destin++
```